# Unable to add transaction to blockchain (I'm invoking the setMessage(str) method but the string i pass doesn't get set but getMessage() method works)

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, metamask, infura

When i call the setMessage() function this doesn't log any transaction in the blockchain. But the getMessage() function works by bringing the message which was previously set using the remix IDE straight away.

If i try to set a message with Remix IDE immediately my metamask opens for the confirmation. This does not happen with my frontend application.

This is what i try to run.

```
<script>

    // Connect a the web3 provider
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/298df63315214b1688a3c2b29e03217d"));
    }

    // Set a default account
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

    //console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount);

    // Get the contract address
    var RemixContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "getMessage",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "x",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "name": "setMessage",
            "outputs": [],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ], '0xa212507364d7E73909Aad1ac114178dDfB48e476');

    console.log(RemixContract);

    $("#setMessageButton").click(function () {
        var val = $("#userInput").val();
        RemixContract.methods.setMessage(val)
        .call()
        .then(function(result){
            console.log(result)
        })
    });

</script>
```

And this is my smart contract in Remix IDE :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Message {
string myMessage;

function setMessage(string x) public {
    myMessage = x;
}

function getMessage() public view returns (string) {
    return myMessage;
}
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the Remix IDE]

Getting the callback response like this:

[image]

Someone kindly let me know what i'm missing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are calling `setMessage` function you should use `send` instead of `call`

```
$("#setMessageButton").click(function () {
        var val = $("#userInput").val();
        RemixContract.methods.setMessage(val)
        .send()
        .then(function(result){
            console.log(result)
        })
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

That helped.

Comment: Still have an error message after using the code above,

Answer (score 0):

@maddie the send function has changed on web3
try this

```
$("#setMessageButton").click(function () {
myMessage.methods.setMessage($("#userInput").val())
.send({from: "<sender account>"})
.then(console.log);

});
```